# Display FindOne query in Nodejs ejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, ejs

I can get all database data to render in my ejs. I am having trouble selecting one record i.e. returning jacks records. The findOne seems to work as console.log on FindOne returns that persons record, but it is not working on the ejs page, getting my No record found message.

Working code for finding all is:

Server.js

```
app.get('/vieworders', require('connect-ensure-login').ensureLoggedIn(), function(req, res) {
          Order.find(function(err, orders) {
          res.render('vieworders', { orders: orders});
      });
});
```

and ejs

```
<h1> Display Orders Here </h1>
<% if(orders.length>0) { %>
<table border="1">
        <tr>
                <th>Index</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>size</th>

        </tr>
        <% for(var i=0; i<orders.length;i++) { %>
                <tr>
                  <td><%= i %></td>
                  <td><%= orders[i].name %></td>
                  <td><%= orders[i].ordersize%></td>
                </tr>
              <% } %>

</table>
<% } else { %>
        No Record Found
      <% } %>
```

What i want is something like the below where instead of getting all record, i only get jacks records

```
app.get('/vieworders', require('connect-ensure-login').ensureLoggedIn(), function(req, res) {

          Order.findOne({name: 'jack'}, function(err, orders) {
          res.render('vieworders', { orders: orders});

      });
});
```

Comment: I imagine `findOne` doesn't return an array, and orders.length is undefined. `0<undefined` returns false, preventing your for-loop from running and throwing an error like "can't read property name of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

FindOne returns only one item, so, in ejs you are getting orders.length 0 or maybe undefined.

Try to change the variable name to order in FindOne and change if like this:

```
<% if(order or orders.length>0) { %>
```